# How to compare a value with a list of value

Tags: excel

Essentially, I try to do the following:

I have three columns with words. i.e:

```
     A            b            C
('soldier'=   ('help=      ('help'=4)     
('weapons'=   ('freedom=   ('freedom'=3)
('freedom=    ('weapons'=  ('weapons'=2)
('help=       ('soldier'=  ('soldier'= 1)
```

What I try to do is to find a formula that if a word from list is identical with a word from list b, then the word with the numeric value of list c should appear. Is there anybody who could help me with that?

Comment: Did you mean: "a word from list **A** is identical with a word from list b"?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant

Comment: Let's put it that way:
I have two lists of words: One in column A and one in Column B - the words in Column B are coded - so they have i.e. ('help'=4), whereas the words in column A are only i.e. ('help'=)
Is there any way that I could assort the numeric values to the words in column A - for the words in column A that match words in column B?

Comment: Please edit your question to be as accurate and clear as possible if you want to get helpful answers. It is very necessary for example that you edit in my comment about list A

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a vlookup formula.

Search for the value in column B in the table named table_Reference.  If the search value is found in the first column of the table, then return the corresponding value of the 2nd column in the table in column C.

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,table_Reference,2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: hi there, thanks, that's not quite what I need. Let's put it that way:
I have two lists of words: One in column A and one in Column B - the words in Column B are coded - so they have i.e. ('help'=4), whereas the words in column A are only i.e. ('help'=)
Is there any way that I could assort the numeric values to the words in column A - for the words in column A that match words in column B?

Comment: So, if the text appearing before the equals sign matches then return the value after the equals sign? Is that what you'd like?